# "my person" as a synonym for myself in specific context

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonyms

First of all, I am not a native English speaker and my understanding of the terms may be biased by other languages I know.. ( hence the question )

In a very official letter I am trying to refer to myself without using the explicit word "`myself`" or "`me`" for fear of repetition ( too many too close ) .

The Phrase i am looking for is along the lines of

> " ..and regarding the proposed meeting Between (me) and X "

1. Can I use the term "my person" in this context ? E.g.

> " ..and regarding the proposed meeting between X and my person ".

or

> " ..and regarding the proposed meeting with my person ".

would a native (American ) English speaker understand it ? find it strange ?

- Alternatively , what other options ( synonyms ) do I have ?
- What is the correct way or context to use "`my person`" as a
  substitute for "me" ( if any ) ?

**Edit I** - Clarification :

- This letter is for a third party regarding a meeting between my self
  and another (second ) party . It is regarding a large company´s board of directors affair, and it involved many meeting and many parties ( some persons, some companies ) but almost always myself . It is potentially be read by both the board itself and other authorities .
- The question is more about the overall "feeling" of the letter . I have
  a very strong feeling about repeating the same word too many time too
  closely . Whenever I read a paragraph that repeats the same word or
  terms too frequently I can not escape the feeling of it being poorly
  constructed . Maybe it is just me , but I can not shake it off and I
  always try to use synonyms in any language I write ..

Comment: Using "my person" to refer to yourself is, er, "quaint", and strongly risks being confused with "my people", meaning your representatives.  I strongly advise against its use.  (There's absolutely nothing wrong with "myself".)

Comment: Something that *might work* is "this party".  But if you're not comfortable with English I'd advise sticking to simpler language.

Comment: "I have a very strong feeling about repeating the same word too many times in a sentence . Whenever I read a paragraph that repeats the same words or terms too frequently, I can not escape the feeling of it being poorly constructed . Maybe it is just me , but I can not shake it off....." It's not just you, I also do not like that aspect. I think you should just go with it and move on, most people (even native speakers), will not notice nor care. Overall your sentence structure is fine, If it is a problem that must resolved, then I would try: "...between myself and name/title".

Comment: '... between X and myself' in a formal register; '... between X and me' in conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Although it might be slightly ambiguous (unless you proposed the meeting [yourself]), you could avoid “me” and “myself” (but not “my”) by taking ownership of the meeting (even if you didn’t propose it) with:

> ..and regarding **my** proposed/scheduled/upcoming meeting with X.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately to "me/myself," which unarguably would be my preferred choice here, you might want to consider the circumlocution ***yours truly***.

> ***yours truly***
>
> For whatever reason of modesty (or false modesty) that prevented
>   speakers or writers from using the first-person singular pronoun "I,"
>   the "yours truly" convention was established. It came from the
>   standard letter closing. It sounded mannered when it was first used in
>   the 19th century and even more so now. Other equally stilted
>   circumlocutions for "I" or "me" used in writing are "your reporter"
>   (still found in alumni class notes) and "your correspondent." [Endangered Phrases by Steven D. Price](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/yours+truly)

Comment: 19th century sounds about right. Recommending 'stilted circumlocutions' even with caveats is of little benefit.